# list in OneToMany Relationship in MVC and entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have tow model 
personnes and diplomes

```
   public class personne
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<diplome> diplomes { get; set; }
}

public class diplome
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string titre { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }

    public int personneId { get; set; }
    public virtual personne personne { get; set; }
}
```

but I'can't display list off diplomes in ditails view

```
  public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        personne personne = db.personnes.Find(id);
        personne.diplomes = db.diplomes.Where(d => d.personneId == id).ToList();

        return View(personne);
    }
```

in the view no acces to diplomes.titre

```
 @foreach (var dep in model.diplomes)//error
    {
        <dd>
             @Html.DisplayFor(dep.titre)
        </dd>
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the DDL:

```
    USE [Breaz]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[diplome]    Script Date: 10/6/2016 1:33:31 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[diplome](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [titre] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [description] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [personneId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_diplome] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[personne]    Script Date: 10/6/2016 1:33:31 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[personne](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_personne] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[diplome]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_diplome_personne] FOREIGN KEY([personneId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[personne] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[diplome] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_diplome_personne]
GO
```

You can then use entity framework (edmx) ADO.NET Entity Data Model.  This generates the tables, as you specified:

```
public partial class personne
{
    public personne()
    {
        this.diplomes = new HashSet<diplome>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<diplome> diplomes { get; set; }
}

    public partial class diplome
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string titre { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> personneId { get; set; }

    public virtual personne personne { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the controller method:

```
public ActionResult Index2()
    {
        BreazEntities entity = new BreazEntities();
        var perso = entity.personnes.ToList();

        return View(perso);
    }
```

Here is the view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
@model IEnumerable<Testy20161006.personne>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
@foreach (var pers in Model)
{
    <section>
        <header>Person is @pers.name</header>
        @foreach (var item in pers.diplomes)
        {
            <p>Dipl: @item.titre</p>
        }
    </section>
} 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```